# overflow:auto causes the absolute elements of child DIV disappeared

Tags: html, css

I have a div 'A' in which I have set `overflow: auto`. Now inside that div, I have two divs: parent div B which is set to `position: relative` and child div C which is `position: absolute`,

Now the issue is that, Setting `overflow: auto` on div A makes div C disappear.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ruoxdwh/2/) which can help you explain my issue.

```
<body style="float:right">

<div id="A" style="overflow:auto;max-height:100px;width:200px;text-align:right">
<div id="B" style="position:relative">A TEXT

<div id="C" style="position:absolute;left:-200px;width:200px;background-color:grey">
  <div id="D">THIS TEXT IS GETTING DISAPPEARED after setting the overflow:auto on the parent DIV with id="A"
  </div><!-- End of DIV with id="D" -->

 </div><!-- End of DIV with id="C" -->

 </div><!-- End of DIV with id="B" -->



 </div><!-- End of DIV with id="A" -->


 </body>
```

Not sure why this is happening, Any help would be highly useful

Comment: @tinthetub So what's the solution? I anyhow need to display C at that position only

Comment: @Deva please make a little sketch and edit your question to make clear what you want to have as a result (maybe a screenshot from your design?). Your markup does not look really clean and a little hacky... I think there is a much cleaner solution possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not disappearing. It's being cut off by the edge of the parent. I edited your fiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/4ruoxdwh/5/

Since you set a `width` and `max-height` on DIV A, setting `overflow:auto` will crop anything outside those boundaries. In the fiddle above, I set background colors and added some padding so you could see it happen.

Notice the scrollbar on the right. If your children don't fit within the dimensions you set, you'll have to either rethink your bounds, or use `overflow:visible`.

Also, for future reference, it will make debugging much easier for you and everyone else if you separate your HTML and CSS as well as using proper indentation.

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="A">
  <div id="B">A TEXT
    <div id="C">
      <div id="D">
        THIS TEXT IS GETTING DISAPPEARED after setting the overflow:auto on the parent DIV with id="A"
      </div><!-- End of DIV with id="D" -->
    </div><!-- End of DIV with id="C" -->
  </div><!-- End of DIV with id="B" -->
</div><!-- End of DIV with id="A" -->

</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  float: right;
}

#A {
  max-height:100px;
  width:200px;
  text-align:right;
  padding: 2em;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: visible;
}

#B {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
}

#C {
  padding: 2em;
  position:absolute;
  left:-200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:green;
}

#D {
  background: cyan;
}
```

Comment: But I need to have overflow : auto or scroll only for A at any cost . And I cannot also change the position of C

Comment: Can you change the dimensions? In your example, the child divs are simply too big and out of place to fit within a 200x100 space. Look at #A. width:200px, but #C is 200px to the left, exactly outside of the dimensions of #A.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here you see why it disappears... Look at your div #A... I gave it a border so you can see its visible area.

```css
body {
    float: right;
}

#A {
    /* overflow: auto; */
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#B {
    position: relative;
}

#C {
    position:absolute;
    left: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
}

#D {
    
}
```

```html
<div id="A">

    <div id="B">A TEXT

        <div id="C">
        
          <div id="D">
              THIS TEXT IS GETTING DISAPPEARED after setting the overflow:auto on the parent DIV with id="A"
          </div><!-- End of DIV with id="D" -->
          
        </div><!-- End of DIV with id="C" -->

    </div><!-- End of DIV with id="B" -->

</div><!-- End of DIV with id="A" -->
```

Comment: So what's the solution? I anyhow need to display C at that position only