# Why Firefox limits visibility of absolute-positioned element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In my project, I have a table screen, that has a navigation bar and a table with sticky header with a button. When a user hovers over this button, tooltip should appear. I want this tooltip to be over the navigation bar. On Chrome it works just fine, but Firefox doesn't show whole tooltip. I made an external div-element for this tooltip. This is a React.js project.
Below I put a code for App.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const paddingTop = 160;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navigation-bar">Navigation Bar</div>
      <div style={{ paddingTop: paddingTop + "px" }}>
        <div>
          <div
            className="table-container"
            style={{
              height: `calc(100vh - ${paddingTop + 10 + 40}px)`
            }}
          >
          <div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: "101" }}>
            <div className="table-header">
              <div className="table-header-content" style={{ top: "167px" }}>
                <div
                  className="btn"
                  onMouseOver={() => setText("My text example")}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setText("")}
                >
                  Button
                </div>
                <div
                  className="tooltip"
                  style={{
                    display: `${text.length > 0 ? "block" : "none"}`
                  }}
                >
                  {text}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="scrollable-content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

And styles.scss:

```
.navigation-bar {
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 100;
}
.table-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.table-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
  height: 45px;
}
.table-header-content {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 10vw;
  right: 10vw;
  height: 25px;
}
.btn {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
.tooltip {
  background-color:rgb(243, 159, 159);
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 101;
}
.scrollable-content {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #aeb6ff;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

And here is also a link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-night-0w4i7h

First I thought, that this tooltip had something to do with `z-index`, but my attempts with experimenting with `z-index` didn't solve the problem.
The tooltip works fine when I remove the `overflow` from `table-container` class, but I need this to scroll only the table.
I thought, that when an element is absolute-positioned, it will have the whole screen at disposal.
Could someone tell me, why my tooltip doesn't work on Firefox?

My screenshot from Firefox:

[image: My screenshot from Firefox]

My screenshot from Chrome:

[image: My screenshot from Chrome]

Comment: Works fine on FF for me. Can you show screenshot of what you see? Maybe there is some other element on top?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) which also includes any other external resources such as fiddles/codepens.

Comment: can confirm that it does NOT work in firefox 97 nor 98 - tooltip also works if you remove the `display:sticky` from one of the ancestor elements (forget which) - but that messes things up horrible

Comment: Same, does not work on mine FF 97

Comment: Thanks for answers. I've added screenshots. My FF version is 97.0.1 (64-bits) and Chrome is 98.0.4758.102 (64-bits). I use Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bits, if it is somehow helpful.

Comment: @Rahdi I stronly suggest you just use the native HTML title attribute

Comment: On Windows 10 Pro it doesn't work either. @Justinas in my original work project there is indeed a navigation bar on top, but here I made sure to not put there anything. It seems like the height of a tooltip's parent with connection to `overflow` and `sticky` properties are causing it.

Comment: @ZachJensz Where? What do you mean?

Comment: @Rahdi On the HTML element, you add the attribute. `<div class="tooltip-info-above" title="text to display when hovered"></div>`

Comment: @ZachJensz I didn't think about it actually, but when I tried your solution and added some CSS (I need the tooltip customized), the problem still occurs. HTML-title-based tooltip behaves the same way when positioned absolute. Firefox hides a fragment of it :(

Answer (score 0):

dear @Rahdi i have two solutions for you.

if you need `.pt-header-above{display:sticky}` then you can change `.table-container{overflow: inherit}`

OR

if you need `.table-container{overflow: hidden;}` then you can change  `.pt-header-above{position: relative}` or remove

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but these solutions unfortunately don't solve my problem :( The tooltip indeed bumps on top, but position of other elements is broken

Comment: but i have checked in firfox browser, its working fine.

Comment: If you change to `.table-container {overflow: inherit}` and scroll down, the content of table will be on top of the navigation bar. If you change to `.table-container {overflow: hidden}`, you can not scroll down the table. The tooltip is visible in these solutions, but other functionality is broken. I've found a workaround and will post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, it seems that this is a default browser behavior and even absolute-positioned children elements are being cut off by their parent with `overflow: auto`. I guess, that the proper question should be rather: "Why is it even working on Chrome?" In this simple example it is demonstrated:

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="A">
  <div id="B">A TEXT
    <div id="C">
      <div id="D">
        THIS TEXT IS GETTING DISAPPEARED after setting the overflow:auto on the parent DIV with id="A"
      </div><!-- End of DIV with id="D" -->
    </div><!-- End of DIV with id="C" -->
  </div><!-- End of DIV with id="B" -->
</div><!-- End of DIV with id="A" -->
```

CSS

```
body {
  float: right;
}

#A {
  max-height:100px;
  width:200px;
  text-align:right;
  padding: 2em;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: visible;
}

#B {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
}

#C {
  padding: 2em;
  position:absolute;
  left:-200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:green;
}

#D {
  background: cyan;
}
```

It is an example from this topic: [overflow:auto causes the absolute elements of child DIV disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456737/overflowauto-causes-the-absolute-elements-of-child-div-disappeared)

In my project I've found a workaround by moving the tooltip element to be at the same level as the navigation bar in HTML tree. It can be then positioned on top by setting `z-index`. Result can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rui-ilbqbl.
However, it is not an optimal solution, because I wanted to avoid updating the state of a component that is many levels higher.